# Is it possible to use two external monitors for my Thinkpad T440p using a Lenovo Ultra Dock?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, lenovo, hdmi, thinkpad

I have a T440p and using it with two external monitors connected through **VGA** and **Mini-Displayport** (one **vertical**, the other horizontal, both 1920*1080) and not using the laptop display itself. I also don’t use a dock and my monitors are connected to laptop directly. I'm planning to buy an ultra dock.

After searching a bit just saw lots of issues with using both VGA and HDMI ports on dock to use two monitors simultaneously. Since nearly all of these threads were older than a year or so, I wanted to check if what I'm trying to do is possible or still there is a problem with that.

I use ubuntu **12.04 LTS**, but if upgrading to 14.04 LTS will solve the problem I can do that.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be lack of MST support in the Linux kernel. Upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 with kernel 3.19 fixed the issue for me, but only after I installed the proprietary nvidia drivers.